# fmap applied to types other than the type variable

Tags: haskell

I have a datatype which keeps track of a 'block' of numbers (kinda like a matrix).

```
newtype Block a = Block [[a]]
```

I would like to make it an instance of `Functor`. However, I am trying to do it in such a way that fmap can apply to the whole list block, so that fmap has type `fmap :: [[a]] -> [[b]]` instead of type `fmap :: a -> b`.

The reason is because I would like to map into my `Block` functor functions like `transpose` which apply to the list block `[[a]]` not to each element `a`. That is, I would like to be able to define functions like

```
transposeBlock :: Block a -> Block a
transposeBlock = (transpose <$>)
```

I tried to declare my functor instance as the following.

```
instance Functor (Block [[a]]) where
  fmap f (Block x) = Block (f x)
```

But I ran into the type errors that arise from attempting to compile this.

```
error:
• Expecting one fewer argument to ‘Block [[a]]’
  Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘Block [[a]]’ has kind ‘*’
• In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘Block [[a]]’
  In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Block [[a]])’
```

What are some ways that I could map functions into the list block `[[a]]` of my `Block` type?

Comment: functor really can't do this, due to it's nature.

Comment: Why not `fmap . fmap :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, you can't call that function `fmap`. But that's okay, there's lots of other good names out there.

```
onBlock :: ([[a]] -> [[b]]) -> Block a -> Block b
onBlock f (Block v) = Block (f v)
```

You can even give it a name full of infixy punctuation goodness if you want.

```
(<#>) :: ([[a]] -> [[b]]) -> Block a -> Block b
f <#> Block v = Block (f v)
```

Comment: Is there really no way to do this with an `fmap`? I jumped on this question quickly, thinking it was easy to fix. Then it didn't sit right and I tried it quickly and couldn't get it to work. Is it because of the kind of `Functor` hiding the `a` in your instance declaration?

Comment: @jkeuhlen You can certainly make `Block` an instance of `Functor`; e.g. [`instance Functor Block where fmap f (Block x) = Block (fmap (fmap f) x)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Compose.html#line-97). But the type of `fmap` doesn't unify with the type of `onBlock`, so using `onBlock` as the implementation is a non-starter.

Comment: Ahh right, because the `a` in `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` will never unify with `[[a]]`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @jkeuhlen, kind of?  Basically, the signature of `fmap` is short for `forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, in other words, it has to work for *any types* `a` and `b` -- including ones which are not lists.  An "fmap" that does not do this doesn't count as a functor -- for example, the generic function `foo x = fmap (+1) x` should work if `x` is an `f Int`, but it wouldn't work on `Block Int` if you got your way.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already commented on the opportunity of using `fmap` for this.

Wrapping / unwrapping `newtype`s is boring, but safe coercions can make this immediate.

```
import Data.Coerce

newtype Block a = Block [[a]]

onBlock :: ([[a]] -> [[b]]) -> Block a -> Block b
onBlock = coerce
```

Indeed, one might even avoid `onBlock` completely, and directly use `coerce` as needed.

Comment: Nice, I'm ashamed I didn't think of this myself! Though I disagree, in that I bet `onBlock` is still worth defining -- every time I have tried to use `coerce` bare, I end up drowning in type annotations.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's true! `coerce` is powerful, but sometimes it needs to be restricted.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve that would be

```
newtype BlockWr a = Block a deriving (Functor)
type Block a = BlockWr [[a]]
```

Now `transposeBlock = (transpose <$>)` would work.

But I wouldn't recommend this. `BlockWr` is just the identity functor, this is not very useful.

Really, the point is that `Block a` is [isomorphic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html) to `[[a]]`. You can witness that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

newtype Block a = Block {_blockMat::[[a]]}
makeLenses ''Block

transposeBlock :: Block a -> Block a
transposeBlock = blockMat %~ transpose
```